# Is there an algorithm to randomly fill a matrix like this?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, graph, nodes

Consider a matrix of r row size and c column size
Given for example r = 19 and c =11, we would have a matrix with 209 elements. All elements have an assigned value of 0. So we have a big matrix containing 0's.

Given the following 6 "areas" 
Area1: 31 elements
Area2: 35 elements
Area3: 35 elements
Area4: 37 elements
Area5: 32 elements
Area6: 39 elements

Summed up all the area elements add up to 209 so they fill the entire matrix.

Is there an algorithm to fill up the matrix with each of these areas and setting the value of the element to the area name?
What I need is actually not the setting part but just the algorithm part that finds an element and the ones near it.

The matrix areas should look like... let's say country teritorries on a world map. So we can't have "area1" elements on the left part of the matrix and then again on the right one with other areas between them. The areas should be condensed, have random "shapes" that get formed when taking over the matrix elements.

Basically, to make it easier to understand I've imagined it like creating random territories of given sizes on a map of a given size (209).

Anybody, any existing algorithm that you can suggest? Or any approach?

Edit:   6 territories ( based on the given example ) that fill the entire space. No background elements( 0 value elements ) should be left. The 6 areas in our example should fill the 209 elements entirely.

Comment: On it. If it makes for anythint. I'm doing it on my small screen sized phone

Comment: You did not define the shapes/area-geometries formally and for most cases it's probably an NP-hard packing-like problem.

Comment: I did not define the shapes because the shapes are supposed to be as random as possible. And I truly have no idea how to do this, nor if it is even possible to have this truly random without any shapes defined.

Comment: interesting problem so +1. Do you have a specific layout where the areas should be placed (center not shape) also what about the background do you allow to have background area (so you got 5 territories and 1 background between them or want 6 territories and no background) ...

Comment: For `n` areas -- at the centre of your space draw `n-2` lines from the centre to the perimeter, equally spaced in angle at the centre.  Then draw one `country` as a blob of however many spaces it occupies at and around the centre.  Place country 2 into the first sector, to occupy enough spaces, ....  Work clockwise round the space.  And now tell us why this simple, and simple-minded, approach doesn't satisfy your requirements.

Comment: See my edit @Spektre

Comment: @Spektre : the example is given above with the 209 element matrix and 6 random (between 20 and 40) sized territories.   This algorithm should be scalable, so for a 900 element matrix we could have 30 territories of size 30. Basically this is not important. It is important that no element of the initial matrix should be let outside the areas when they are defined

Comment: I will try to implement your approach. Sounds like a good idea @High Performance Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain some randomness I approach this problem like this:

1. **generate seed start point per teritory**

   simply compute random start point for each territory with constraint that any 2 start points must have at least some defined minimal distance between each other. That will provide some room for growth so the result is looking better.
2. **grow each seed while you can**

   simply enlarge each territory iteratively until there is no gap present (ignoring the desired territory size)
3. **correct the sizes**

   so simply take territory `i=1` and enlarge/shrink them from any neighboring territory `j>i`. then process `i=2` ... when done do the same in decreasing order so take territory `i=n` and enlarge/shrink from any neighbor `j<i`.

   loop this whole thing until the territories has correct sizes
4. **verify**

   bullet **#3** can divide some territories into non consequent areas which is I suspect undesirable. So detect this and if the case generate this whole thing again.

   To detect this just for each territory find its first valid cell and flood-fill 
   count how bigg that territory is. If not matching the size the territory has been divided and you should generate again.

   If all territories match sizes then map is relevant and you're done

**Here preview of #1,#2,#3:**

[image: preview]

The numbers in the form captions are the territories `actual size - wanted size` first number is gap and then goes territory `1,2,3 ...`

**And my C++ implementation:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// generator properties
const int n=7;          // teritories+1
const int mx=19;        // map size
const int my=11;
const int siz[n]={ 0,31,35,35,37,32,39 };   // teritory sizes (first is bordrer)
const int mindist=5;    // min distance between teritory seed points
      int map[mx][my];  // map 0 means no teritory else it is teritory ID
// rendering properties
const int grid=16;      // grid size [pixels]
const DWORD col[n]=     // teritory color table
    {
    0x00000000,         // border (unused)
    0x00FF0000,         // territory 1
    0x0000FF00,         // territory 2
    0x000000FF,         // territory 3
    0x00FFFF00,         // territory 4
    0x0000FFFF,         // territory 5
    0x00FF00FF,         // territory 6
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void map_generate()
    {
    int x,y,xx,yy,i,j,e;
    int cnt[n];     // generated teritory size
    int seedx[n];   // start position for teritory
    int seedy[n];

//  AnsiString s="";
//  s+=AnsiString().sprintf("Seed: %X |",RandSeed);

    for (;;)
        {
        // clear map
        cnt[0]=mx*my;
        for (x=0;x<mx;x++)
         for (y=0;y<my;y++)
          map[x][y]=0;
        // start position
        for (i=1;i<n;)
            {
            // ranom position
            seedx[i]=Random(mx);
            seedy[i]=Random(my);
            // find closest seed point x = distance to it
            for (x=mx+my,j=1;j<i;j++)
                {
                y=abs(seedx[i]-seedx[j])+abs(seedy[i]-seedy[j]);
                if (x>y) x=y;
                }
            // if OK use as seed point else repeat the whole thing again...
            if (x>mindist)
                {
                map[seedx[i]][seedy[i]]=i;
                cnt[i]=1; cnt[0]--; i++;
                }
            }

        // un bounded growth fill (can exceeding area)
        for (e=1;e;)
            {
            e=0;
            for (x=   1;x<mx;x++) for (y=0;y<my;y++) { i=map[x][y]; if (i>0){ x--; if (map[x][y]==0) { map[x][y]=i; cnt[i]++; cnt[0]--; e=1; } x++; }}
            for (x=mx-2;x>=0;x--) for (y=0;y<my;y++) { i=map[x][y]; if (i>0){ x++; if (map[x][y]==0) { map[x][y]=i; cnt[i]++; cnt[0]--; e=1; } x--; }}
            for (x=0;x<mx;x++) for (y=   1;y<my;y++) { i=map[x][y]; if (i>0){ y--; if (map[x][y]==0) { map[x][y]=i; cnt[i]++; cnt[0]--; e=1; } y++; }}
            for (x=0;x<mx;x++) for (y=my-2;y>=0;y--) { i=map[x][y]; if (i>0){ y++; if (map[x][y]==0) { map[x][y]=i; cnt[i]++; cnt[0]--; e=1; } y--; }}
            }

        // correct inequalities cnt[] vs. siz[]
        for (;;)
            {
            // stop if all counts are matching
            for (i=1;i<n;i++) if (cnt[i]!=siz[i]) { i=-1; break; } if (i>=0) break;
            // growth i from any neighbor j>i
            for (i=1;i<n;i++)
             for (e=1;(e)&&(cnt[i]<siz[i]);)
                {
                e=0;
                for (x=   1;x<mx;x++) for (y=0;y<my;y++) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]<siz[i])){ x--; j=map[x][y]; if ((i<j)&&(cnt[j]>1)){ map[x][y]=i; cnt[i]++; cnt[j]--; e=1; } x++; }
                for (x=mx-2;x>=0;x--) for (y=0;y<my;y++) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]<siz[i])){ x++; j=map[x][y]; if ((i<j)&&(cnt[j]>1)){ map[x][y]=i; cnt[i]++; cnt[j]--; e=1; } x--; }
                for (x=0;x<mx;x++) for (y=   1;y<my;y++) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]<siz[i])){ y--; j=map[x][y]; if ((i<j)&&(cnt[j]>1)){ map[x][y]=i; cnt[i]++; cnt[j]--; e=1; } y++; }
                for (x=0;x<mx;x++) for (y=my-2;y>=0;y--) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]<siz[i])){ y++; j=map[x][y]; if ((i<j)&&(cnt[j]>1)){ map[x][y]=i; cnt[i]++; cnt[j]--; e=1; } y--; }
                }
            // shrink i from any neighbor j>i
            for (i=1;i<n;i++)
             for (e=1;(e)&&(cnt[i]>siz[i]);)
                {
                e=0;
                for (x=   1;x<mx;x++) for (y=0;y<my;y++) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]>siz[i])){ x--; j=map[x][y]; if (i<j)              { map[x+1][y]=j; cnt[j]++; cnt[i]--; e=1; } x++; }
                for (x=mx-2;x>=0;x--) for (y=0;y<my;y++) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]>siz[i])){ x++; j=map[x][y]; if (i<j)              { map[x-1][y]=j; cnt[j]++; cnt[i]--; e=1; } x--; }
                for (x=0;x<mx;x++) for (y=   1;y<my;y++) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]>siz[i])){ y--; j=map[x][y]; if (i<j)              { map[x][y+1]=j; cnt[j]++; cnt[i]--; e=1; } y++; }
                for (x=0;x<mx;x++) for (y=my-2;y>=0;y--) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]>siz[i])){ y++; j=map[x][y]; if (i<j)              { map[x][y-1]=j; cnt[j]++; cnt[i]--; e=1; } y--; }
                }

            // stop if all counts are matching
            for (i=1;i<n;i++) if (cnt[i]!=siz[i]) { i=-1; break; } if (i>=0) break;
            // growth i from any neighbor j<i
            for (i=n-1;i>0;i--)
             for (e=1;(e)&&(cnt[i]<siz[i]);)
                {
                e=0;
                for (x=   1;x<mx;x++) for (y=0;y<my;y++) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]<siz[i])){ x--; j=map[x][y]; if ((i>j)&&(cnt[j]>1)){ map[x][y]=i; cnt[i]++; cnt[j]--; e=1; } x++; }
                for (x=mx-2;x>=0;x--) for (y=0;y<my;y++) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]<siz[i])){ x++; j=map[x][y]; if ((i>j)&&(cnt[j]>1)){ map[x][y]=i; cnt[i]++; cnt[j]--; e=1; } x--; }
                for (x=0;x<mx;x++) for (y=   1;y<my;y++) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]<siz[i])){ y--; j=map[x][y]; if ((i>j)&&(cnt[j]>1)){ map[x][y]=i; cnt[i]++; cnt[j]--; e=1; } y++; }
                for (x=0;x<mx;x++) for (y=my-2;y>=0;y--) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]<siz[i])){ y++; j=map[x][y]; if ((i>j)&&(cnt[j]>1)){ map[x][y]=i; cnt[i]++; cnt[j]--; e=1; } y--; }
                }
            // shrink i from any neighbor j<i
            for (i=n-1;i>0;i--)
             for (e=1;(e)&&(cnt[i]>siz[i]);)
                {
                e=0;
                for (x=   1;x<mx;x++) for (y=0;y<my;y++) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]>siz[i])){ x--; j=map[x][y]; if (i>j)              { map[x+1][y]=j; cnt[j]++; cnt[i]--; e=1; } x++; }
                for (x=mx-2;x>=0;x--) for (y=0;y<my;y++) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]>siz[i])){ x++; j=map[x][y]; if (i>j)              { map[x-1][y]=j; cnt[j]++; cnt[i]--; e=1; } x--; }
                for (x=0;x<mx;x++) for (y=   1;y<my;y++) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]>siz[i])){ y--; j=map[x][y]; if (i>j)              { map[x][y+1]=j; cnt[j]++; cnt[i]--; e=1; } y++; }
                for (x=0;x<mx;x++) for (y=my-2;y>=0;y--) if ((i==map[x][y])&&(cnt[i]>siz[i])){ y++; j=map[x][y]; if (i>j)              { map[x][y-1]=j; cnt[j]++; cnt[i]--; e=1; } y--; }
                }
            }
        // test if teritories are not divided and regenerate if needed
        for (xx=0,i=1;i<n;i++)
            {
            // clear temp bit
            for (x=0;x<mx;x++)
             for (y=0;y<my;y++)
              map[x][y]&=65535;
            // find first occurence
            j=0;
            for (x=0;x<mx;x++)
             for (y=0;y<my;y++)
              if (map[x][y]==i) { map[x][y]|=65536; j=1; x=mx; y=my; }
            if (!j) { xx=1; break; }        // teritory not found
            // growth fill count into j
            for (e=1;e;)
             for (e=0,x=0;x<mx;x++)
              for (   y=0;y<my;y++)
               if (map[x][y]==i)
                {
                yy=0;
                if ((x>   0)&&(map[x-1][y]>=65536)) yy=1;
                if ((x<mx-1)&&(map[x+1][y]>=65536)) yy=1;
                if ((y>   0)&&(map[x][y-1]>=65536)) yy=1;
                if ((y<my-1)&&(map[x][y+1]>=65536)) yy=1;
                if (yy){ j++; map[x][y]|=65536; e=1; }
                }
            if (j!=siz[i]) { xx=1; break; } // teritory incorrect size
            }
        if (xx) continue;                   // regenerate again
        // clear temp bit
        for (x=0;x<mx;x++)
         for (y=0;y<my;y++)
          map[x][y]&=65535;
        break;                              // al OK so stop
        }

//  for (i=0;i<n;i++) { s+=cnt[i]-siz[i]; s+=" "; }
//  Main->Caption=s;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The code is not optimized to keep it as simple and understandable as I could... (can be recoded to be much much faster).

Comment: I'm trying a few more options, yours included. Eventually I will come back with a different answer or accept yours as the correct one.

Thank your for all the effort, you truly helped, if not with the entire algorithm, at least with a handful of great insight and ideas :)